# Issue with regex replaceAll

Tags: java, regex, replaceall

I'm trying to turn, `a/b/c.x.y` into `abc`. However there seems to be an issue with my regular expression, specifically with `'\\.*'`.

```
 "a/b/c.x".replaceAll( "/|\\.*", "" );
```

yields:

```
 "abcx"
```

Any insight would be great, thanks!

Comment: Is that the only format it will ever be in? Because a/b.x/c would require some different logic.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're replacing any slash or "any number of dots" with an empty string.

I suspect you mean any slash or "a dot followed by any number of any characters" which would be:

```
replaceAll("/|\\..*", "");
```

That certainly works for me with the sample value.

Comment: Just what I was typing. Rule isn't clear from the question, but the `*` implies this is what the OP was after.

Answer (score 0):

Your current regex matches a forward slash OR zero or more periods. I assume that you want to match forward slash OR a period plus anything after it. For that, you want

```
"/|\\..*"
```